# autotab to next input field is not working after jQuery validation

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have 3 textbox like below, i would like to add autotab to this input field and is working very first. When the validation comes ie after validation error the autotab functionality is not working. when these inputs are empty validation will work and will focus on red as required at that time i cant see the autotab functionality. Please help me to solve this.

```
<input type="text" name="otp1" id= "otp1" class="otp-btn" maxlength="1">
<input type="text" name="otp2" id= "otp2" class="otp-btn" maxlength="1">
<input type="text" name="otp3" id= "otp3" class="otp-btn" maxlength="1">

 $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#updatePassForm input:text").first().focus();
    $(".otp-btn").keyup(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (this.value.length == this.maxLength) {
      $(this).next('.otp-btn').focus();
    }
}); 

    $('#updatePassForm').validate({
      rules: {
        otp1: {
          required: true,
        },
        otp2: {
          required: true,
        },
        otp3: {
          required: true,
        },
      },
      messages: {
        otp1: {
          required: '',       
        },
        otp2: {
          required: '',       
        },
       otp3: {
          required: '',       
        },
      },
      submitHandler: function (form) {
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that, `next` function of jQuery selector **get the immediately following sibling item**. So when the validation show the `next` refer to an error label generated by jquery et since it does not have the css class `otp-btn`, it is not focused.

So a solution would be to sibling all subsequent elements that have the class `otp-btn` and then retrieve the first element.

#### something like this: `.nextAll('.otp-btn').first()` instead of `.next('.otp-btn')`